# Procedure to export/import xml file on selected path

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, export

I looking for how to export and import generated from table xml file to a selected path. Path to the file is must be as parameter becouse user in C# program will send path to save it on disk. I do little research and found this but it's don't saying very much to me. Here is link: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4963/simple-image-import-and-export-using-tsql-for-sql-server/

I don't use sql server too much and that's why im here

Comment: If you don't understand the article, tell us what it is you don't understand so that we can try and explain it for you. What you are stating here is far too broad. You haven't asked a question here either, what is your question? Asking for a "how to" guide is off-topic for Stack Overflow; you're question need to be able to specific programming question. Thanks.

Comment: If this functionality is something your user will choose to do, then use of a stored procedure is most likely the wrong implementation choice. Your user will decide where the file is created and it is very unlikely that any stored procedure will be able to access that path due to permissions. Ask your coworkers or seniors for guidance.